# Does it matter which widget's after method I use?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am experimenting with the `after` method most `Tkinter` widgets possess.

Here's my demo:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import random

# set up main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 100)

# set up function that gets a random widget from the UI
def all_widgets(root=root):
    for w in root.winfo_children():
        yield w
        if isinstance(w, ttk.Frame):
            for ww in walk_widgets(w):
                yield ww

def random_widget():
    return random.choice(list(all_widgets()))

# create two scales ...
kw = dict(master=root, from_=0, to=10, length=500)
scale1 = ttk.Scale(**kw)
scale1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

scale2 = ttk.Scale(**kw)
scale2.grid(row=1, column=0)

# ... that jump randomly once a second
delay = 1000

def jump(scale):
    scale.set(random.randint(0, 10))
    random_widget().after(delay, lambda: jump(scale))

jump(scale1)
jump(scale2)

root.mainloop()
```

This creates two scales that randomly jump once a second.

[image]

It uses the `after` method of random widgets. Am I missing something or is it completely arbitrary on which widget I call `after`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you. For some reason I could not find that question.

Comment: I only asked it a month ago. Google doesn't give it very much importance. It was buried in a list in the results when I searched for it. I almost missed it, and I knew it existed.